# Missing datasource in ejb-jar.xml

Tags: jndi, websphere-6.1

If I deploy an EAR on a WAS and the EAR is missing an EJB described in ejb-jar.xml, it complains at deployment time. But if I have defined a resource-ref for a jndi datasource in ejb-jar.xml, it does not complain unless i execute a test case that actually tries to lookup the datasource.

Is there a configuration that can be  tweaked so that when deploying an EAR, it will complain if any of the resource-references have not been created on the server? So that I know immediately that some resource-references are missing